# BITOP NOT is not working correctly in Redis 5.0.5

Tags: redis

I am using Redis 5.0.5 version. I am seeing strange behavior while working with BITOP NOT operator.
Below is my observation:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set shank_m 111000  
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> set shank_f 000111 
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> set shank_s 100001
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> bitop or tmp1 shank_m shank_f
(integer) 6
127.0.0.1:6379> get tmp1 
"111111"     // Returns correct result for OR operator
127.0.0.1:6379> bitop not tmp2 shank_s
(integer) 6
127.0.0.1:6379> get tmp2  
"\xce\xcf\xcf\xcf\xcf\xce" //It seems that it's not performing bit operation correctly
```

Please note the value of tmp2 should be **0111110**. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using it wrong :)

To set a key to with bitmap/bitarray values you'll need to use the [`BITSET` command](https://redis.io/commands/bitset), like so:

```
SETBIT shank_m 0 1
SETBIT shank_m 1 1
SETBIT shank_m 2 1
SETBIT shank_f 3 1
SETBIT shank_f 4 1
SETBIT shank_f 5 1
SETBIT shank_s 0 1
SETBIT shank_s 5 1
```

What you're doing is setting the key be the literal string value of "111000".

Comment: This will eventually be represented as a string in Redis.. right? What you are doing is adding it one by one instead of my approach where I am doing it in bulk.

Comment: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/1759 actually helped me in understanding as to what's going on.

Comment: After answering your question I had realized that your "mistake" is actually a problem with the documentation. Please have a look at https://github.com/antirez/redis-doc/pull/1186 and let me know if it helps/can be improved/etc... - thanks for helping by asking!

Comment: thanks for this. But I am still not able to understand how can I do bulk set operation from the command line for bits.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the need - why would someone want to use the cli to set multiple bits? You'd usually do it from your code.

Comment: Ok got it :). I just wanted to confirm if I understood it right.